# clone HDD to bigger HDD - align to sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, clone, gparted

I have a 320 gb HDD, which is too small for me.
There is a Windows 7 OS on it.
I would like to clone this HDD onto a 1TB HDD, using Parted Magic or gparted.

The HDD on the 1TB has a 320 GB partition after cloning, it has to be resized.

Question: Do I have to do anything else for resizing? Some sort of alining on the sectors? Or is this only for SSDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can just re-size :)

I personally use AOMEI Partition Assistant to manage partitions, this is a Windows program that does this easily

I hope i answered your question!